# UIActivityView Controller add "Print"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have added an 'UIActivityViewController' this works very well but the "Print" button is not shown.
How can I add the "Print" Button? I will print out the actual PDF file which is shown in an 'UIWebView' named "background".

Perfectly: That not the URL will be sent by email oder post on twitter/facebook special the pdf as Picture

here is my code:

```
NSArray *items = @[self.background.request.URL.absoluteString];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {

};

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
```

EDIT:
How Can I print out the actual PDF shown in UIWebView as Image?
And how can I add the Printer Button?

Answer (score -1):

Try to explicitly include a `UIActivity` of type `UIActivityTypePrint` in your `applicationActivities` when initialising the activity view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Can you give me a example?